# HTML e-mail viewer in wxPython

Tags: html, wxpython

I have a wxPython application that sends multipart emails with HTML and embedded images. As part of the sending process every email gets stored away as-is (RFC822 format) for future reference..
My question is: what would you recommend to show these emails from the application itself?

(Xubuntu 8.10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind opening the default email client on the user's system you can use the desktop module to do so (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/desktop).

Comment: I hacked together a solution for simple e-mails.. 1) A mail parser that extracts HTML + images from the mail and 2) an HtmlWindow that displays them..
Anyway since HtmlWindow is suitable only for very basic HTML I'll have to ditch that solution soon, so thanks for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution: [embedded WebKit](http://wxwebkit.kosoftworks.com) (when it's ready)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution: [wxWebconnect](http://www.kirix.com/labs/wxwebconnect.html) (not quite ready for Linux yet)

Comment: I have used wxWebConnect on Linux, but would probably agree it's not quite ready (still).  Difficult to configure and set up and relies on a specific version of XULRunner (at present, 1.9.2).  I plan to change this sometime to at least support 2.0, but it hasn't made its way high up on my priority list yet.